# Xpages cannot get getComponent to work in Ext:Dialog

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have an value picker in a dialog box. The user selects a value and that value is entered into an Edit Box, which is bound to a scope variable. So far so good.

I then have a button where I want to ask the access the value that is in the edit box.

I have tried using

```
var satLoc:String = viewScope.get("selLoc");
var satLoc:String = getComponent("selLoc").getValue();
```

neither of which works - I just get null.

My code is below. I would appreciate some help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

    <xp:button id="button15" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:8pt" value="Load Satellite Dialog">                          
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="dialogAddSat">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var d = getComponent('dialogAddSat')d.show()}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

    <xp:br></xp:br>

    <xe:dialog id="dialogAddSat" style="width:300px">
            <xe:this.title><![CDATA[#{javascript:"Make This Location A Hub"}]]></xe:this.title>
            <xe:dialogButtonBar>
                <xp:table id="tblCrd" style="width:99.0%">
                    <xp:tr>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xp:label id="label24" for="region" value="Hub Location Number" />
                        </xp:td>
                        <xp:td> 
                        <xe:djTextBox id="djTextBox2"
                            style="width:35px;text-align:right">
                            <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
                                <xp:dojoAttribute name="readOnly"
                                    value="true">
                                </xp:dojoAttribute>
                            </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
                            <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:"0002"}]]></xe:this.value><xp:eventHandler event="onChange"
                                submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="tblCrd">
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xe:djTextBox>
                        </xp:td>
                        <xp:td style="text-align:right">

                        <xp:button id="button13" value="Attach Satellite">
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                submit="true" refreshMode="complete" id="eventHandler7"
                                disableValidators="true">
                                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.closeDialog('#{id:dialogMakeHub}');]]></xp:this.script>
                                <xp:this.action>
                                    <xp:actionGroup>
                                        <xp:confirm>
                                    <xp:this.message><![CDATA[#{javascript:try {
    var satLoc:String = viewScope.get("selLoc");
    //var satLoc:String = getComponent("selLoc").getValue();
    var hubLoc = "0002";
    //var hubLoc:String = document1.getDocument().getItemValueString("locNum");
    return "Make Location " + satLoc + " a Satellite for Location Number " + hubLoc
} catch(e){
    return e;
}

}]]></xp:this.message>
                                        </xp:confirm>
                                        <xp:executeScript>
                                            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:print ("Here")}]]></xp:this.script>
                                        </xp:executeScript>
                                    </xp:actionGroup>
                                </xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:button></xp:td>
                    </xp:tr>
                    <xp:tr>
                        <xp:td>
                            <xp:label id="label25" for="region" value="Select Location..." />
                        </xp:td><xp:td>
    <xp:inputText id="selLoc" value="#{viewScope.selLoc}"></xp:inputText>
    <xe:valuePicker id="valuePicker77"
        dialogTitle="Choose A Location To Add As A Satellite"
        pickerIcon="/picker.png" for="selLoc">

        <xe:this.dataProvider>
            <xe:simpleValuePicker>
                <xe:this.valueList><![CDATA[#{javascript:import xpUtilities

var tmpLocView:NotesView = database.getView("(DbLocsOperActiveLOnly)");
var arr = new Array();
var tmpLocNum:String;
var hubLocNum:String;

//hubLocNum = padToFour(document1.getDocument().getItemValueString("locNum"));
hubLocNum = "0002;"
//arr[0] = hublocNum

var tmpLocDoc:NotesDocument = tmpLocView.getFirstDocument();
while (tmpLocDoc != null) {
    tmpLocNum = tmpLocDoc.getItemValueString("locNum");
    if (tmpLocNum != hubLocNum)
    {arr.push(tmpLocDoc.getItemValueString("locNum"));}
    var tmpdoc = tmpLocView.getNextDocument(tmpLocDoc);
    tmpLocDoc.recycle();
    tmpLocDoc = tmpdoc;
}

return arr
}]]></xe:this.valueList>
            </xe:simpleValuePicker>
        </xe:this.dataProvider>
    </xe:valuePicker></xp:td>
                        <xp:td style="text-align:right">

                        <xp:button value="Cancel" id="button10">
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                submit="true" refreshMode="complete" id="eventHandler4">
                                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.closeDialog('#{id:dialogAddSat}')]]></xp:this.script>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:button></xp:td>
                    </xp:tr>
                    <xp:tr>
                        <xp:td>
                        </xp:td>
                        <xp:td>
                        </xp:td>
                        <xp:td style="text-align:right">
                        </xp:td>
                    </xp:tr>
                </xp:table>
            </xe:dialogButtonBar>
        </xe:dialog>
</xp:view>
```

[image]

I have found a solution. I had an action group with a Confirmation Action. I was trying to get the value in the confirmation action. For some reason, it doesn't work there. I just ignore it in the confirmation action and now it work.

Comment: Does it show as being in viewScope in your debug toolbar?  If you don't have the debug toolbar, then download from openNTF.

Comment: OK downloaded it and installed in Designer. Trying to use it on local, but getting an error [see above].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is about the timing. On the following code, you compute a confirmation text. But this is being computed at the server side, when it's being rendered. At the time of rendering, the viewScope variable is empty.

```
<xp:button 
    id="button13" 
    value="Attach Satellite">
    <xp:eventHandler 
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete"
        id="eventHandler7"
        disableValidators="true">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.closeDialog('#{id:dialogMakeHub}');]]></xp:this.script>
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:actionGroup>
                <xp:confirm>
                    <xp:this.message><![CDATA[#{javascript:try {
var satLoc:String = viewScope.get("selLoc");
//var satLoc:String = getComponent("selLoc").getValue();
var hubLoc = "0002";
//var hubLoc:String = document1.getDocument().getItemValueString("locNum");
return "Make Location " + satLoc + " a Satellite for Location Number " + hubLoc
} catch(e){
return e;
}}]]>
                    </xp:this.message>
                </xp:confirm>
                <xp:executeScript>
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:print ("Here")}]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:executeScript>
            </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

If you refresh the button component when the input value changes, it will show the correct value. However, I'd prefer computing the value of the confirmation on the client side, in the script attribute. Closing dialog should be the final action (if the user does not confirm the value, it shouldn't be closed. Here is the modified version.

```
<xp:button
    id="button13"
    value="Attach Satellite">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete"
        id="eventHandler7"
        onComplete="XSP.closeDialog('#{id:dialogAddSat}');"
        disableValidators="true">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:actionGroup>
                <xp:executeScript>
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:print ("Here")}]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:executeScript>
            </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action>
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[return confirm("Location will be set "+dojo.byId('#{id:selLoc}').value+". Confirm?")]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Comment: Serdar, this is awesome. I had a feeling it was about timing. This solution worked perfectly - thank you very much.

Comment: Serdar, very quick question if you do not mind. I want the piece of data the user selects in this dialog box to appear in the underlying document. How do I refresh the component on the underlying document?

Comment: I generally set the value within executeScript section. It refreshes everything now: `refreshMode=complete` You might change it to `partial` and provide a `refreshId` to make a partial refresh. Another alternative is calling a partial refresh after XSP.closeDialog, as explained here: http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_events_and_partial_or_full_refresh

Comment: I understand now. The problem I am having is I am calling a method from a script library, and that is where the save is taking place - I am adding a field to a multi-value field and have to have it in the correct order and do some other things as well. What I need is to pause (or use a callback?) so the action doesn't continue until the script is done. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Your method is client side or server side? For the server side, it does wait for the operation to be completed before refresh. On the client side, you can update the value and no need to refresh the value (it will be submitted on the next action).

Comment: I am using server side. What I need to refresh is a view (kind of like an embedded view), that shows documents that are attached to the parent document. When the dialogbox closes, the view in the xpgage does not contain the document, but if I refresh the page manuallu it does. It is strange.

Comment: It is on the server side. The component I want to refresh is a view that contains the documents that I am attaching to the main document (kind of like an embedded view). I tried change to partial and refresh that ID but it didn't work. Strange.

Comment: Ah! That's because it's binded to a view data source. Views cache data in the view scope by default. You might change it with scope attribute in the view data source. If you change that to request, it will refresh its data for every requests (including partial refreshes). However, that's a bad practice for performance.

Comment: You might try `getComponent("viewPanelId").getDataSource().refresh();` for updating its content at the server side.